# Hiding sum of vectors. Hardness based on CVP

Tags: encryption, lattice-crypto, commitments

This is the problem

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a lattice and $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\notin\mathcal{L}$. Given the values $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ such that

$$a_1=\lfloor v_1\rceil+v_2+\ldots+v_n$$
$$a_2=v_1+\lfloor v_2\rceil+\ldots+v_n$$
$$\vdots$$
$$a_n=v_1+v_2+\ldots+\lfloor v_n\rceil$$

where $\lfloor\cdot\rceil$ means projection to $\mathcal{L}$. Retreive $\Sigma:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_i$.

Paraphrasing, say Alice lets Bob know $\mathcal{L}$, the $a_i$'s and the way they're constructed (i.e. the system above). How hard it is for Bob to obtain $\Sigma$?

For instance, if Bob manages to obtain $v_j$ for some $j$, then he *only* needs to compute $\lfloor v_j\rceil$ and $a_j-\lfloor v_j\rceil+v_j$ to obtain $\Sigma$. Therefore, at this point, the secrecy of $\Sigma$ relies on the secrecy of the $v_i$'s and the CVP.

Of course obtaining all the $v_i$'s will give it away immediately avoiding CVP, but that seems hard at first glance.

Regards

Comment: It sounds an interesting problem, but I have a question, you mean that $ \lfloor v \rceil$  is the closet lattice points to $v$ right?  But there may be many such lattice points, thus if $v_i$ satisfied that $ \lfloor v_i \rceil$ is unique, then the question is unambiguous.

Comment: Sorry, I an wrong. More generally, You can interpret $\lfloor\cdot\rceil$  as some random algorithm. This problem is likely to be difficult in this sense, and it is likely to be easy in the sense mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

The below is essentially a comment, but perhaps long for one.

There are a number of ways which this problem seems underspecified currently.
For example, does one need to *exactly* obtain $\Sigma$, or is *approximately* obtaining it bad as well?
One method to approximately obtain it is

$$\frac{\sum_i a_i}{n} = \Sigma + \frac{\sum_i v_i\bmod\mathcal{L}}{n}.$$

Here, $x\bmod\mathcal{L} := x - \lfloor x\rceil$.
If $v_i$ is randomly sampled, under suitable assumptions of the underlying distribution (which are somewhat common), we will have that $\mathbb{E}[v_i\bmod\mathcal{L}] = 0$, and moreover $v_i$ is (at least close to) uniform on $\mathcal{V} = \{x\mid \lfloor x\rceil = 0\} = \mathbb{R}^m\bmod \mathcal{L}.$
Then $\frac{\sum_i v_i\bmod\mathcal{L}}{n}$ can be seen as an empirical/sample mean.
By things  like the Central Limit Theorem, it will be distributed as $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2/n)$ for large-enough $n$, where $\sigma^2 = \mathsf{Var}[v_i\bmod\mathcal{L}]$.
Therefore if $n\gg \sigma^2$, one starts to expect significant issues, even if we have to *exactly* obtain $\Sigma$.
If we only have to *approximately* obtain $\Sigma$, the problem of course becomes significantly easier.
This is to say that the hardness of your problem seems closely-related to the ratio $\sigma^2/n$.
This makes sense --- when this quantity is small, $\lfloor x\rceil\approx x$, and $a_i\approx \Sigma$ already.
When this quantity is large, this is no longer true.

---

Note that there are other potential issues as well, namely the pairwise differences $a_i - a_j = v_j\bmod\mathcal{L} - v_i\bmod\mathcal{L}$ are efficiently computable.
This doesn't *directly* seem to cause issues, but it seems uncomfortably close to causing issues.
If one can get many samples of $x\mapsto x\bmod \mathcal{L}$, one can

1. use this to extract a description of $\mathcal{V}$, and then
2. use this to construct an oracle for $\lfloor x\rceil$.

I believe this is (roughly) the content on the various "learning a hidden basis" papers, attacking things like GGH and NTRUSign.

Here, we don't precisely get samples of the form $x\mapsto x\bmod \mathcal{L}$.
Instead, we get the weaker samples $(v_i, v_j)\mapsto v_i\bmod\mathcal{L} - v_j\bmod\mathcal{L}$.
Perhaps this thwarts the previously-mentioned attacks, but it is not clear to me, and it is adjacent to something which is vulnerable to attacks.

Concretely, given enough samples (and under some assumptions), I expect an attacker to be able to learn $\mathcal{V} + \mathcal{V}$, where $A+B = \{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$.
If somehow they can "divide by two", i.e. go from $2\mathcal{V} := \mathcal{V}+\mathcal{V}$ to $\mathcal{V}$, I expect there to be a straightforward attack on the proposal via constructing a CVP oracle for $\lfloor \cdot \rceil$.
I won't look into this further myself, but it is a somewhat-concerning potential way to attack your proposed problem.

Comment: Thanks for writing what I wanted to say，I have the same opinion as you, and the paper of  Ducas and Nguyen paper ''Learning a Zonotope and More: Cryptanalysis of NTRUSign Countermeasures'' is relevant